# Audio amplifier using LM386L

Tags: amplifier, audio

I am a student and I am trying to build an audio amplifier.

I wanted to ask if there's any way to replace capacitors with different (some in pF). If it could be possible, let me know. I'm using 9V battery

I have these caps:

- 104pF (5PCS) Ceramic Capacitor
- 22pF (5PCS)Ceramic Capacitor
- 100uF (2PCS) Electrolytic Capacitor
- 10uF (2PCS) Electrolytic Capacitor

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICTOg.gif): https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpRTw.gif[image]

Comment: You _might_ be able to get away without any of those capacitors, though putting in the 250μF one would be a good idea as it will keep DC out of your speaker (which can damage it). The 0.05μF one looks like part of a snubber network, though, which may be necessary to ensure the LM386 is stable and doesn't oscillate; check what the datasheet says.

Comment: One thing, tho. Is there any difference between LM386L and LM386?

Comment: Again, check the datasheet. They are almost certainly just different variants of the same part and probably have no difference that matters for this application, but I can't guarantee that.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will. I wonder what the problem was because when I did everything in the picture except having those precise values of capacitors, I heard some quiet noise as well quiet sound from my mobile when I played a music. I had to bend my head to hear the sound. Is it because of capacitors? I tried setting the volume with that potentiometer and it was worse.

Comment: By the way, are you sure that's 104pF and not 100nF?

Comment: Yes, it's on the leaflet. By the way, you said ''... though putting in the 250μF would be a good idea''. Can I just make two 100 uF electrolytic capacitors parallel? Would that do it?

Comment: The "104pF" cap is almost certainly a 100nF cap.  "104pF" would imply a 1% precision or better, which is an insane precision for a cap -- if it says "104" on it, then it's almost certainly a 100nF.  If so, it'd be perfect from pin 7 to ground, and from pin 6 to pin 4 (always bypass the power leads -- you don't see it in data sheets because it's just assumed).  It'd also work in place of the \$.05\mu\mathrm{F}\$ (50nF) cap, although a 47nF would be better.

Comment: What "leaflet" says it's a 104pF cap?  Was it written by an educator or someone who's actually functioned well in industry?  Can you post a picture of the cap and the leaflet?  Yes, putting two 100uF caps in parallel would work -- three would be better.

Comment: You can look at it, it's added in the question

Comment: @MerryGR I'm pretty sure that's a 100nF cap and whoever wrote that leaflet doesn't know what they're talking about. As for the 250μF cap, the exact value of that doesn't matter too much. 100μF is probably good enough, but you can parallel two 100μF caps if you want.

Comment: @TimWescott Alerting you to the asker's comment because they didn't tag you when replying to you.

Comment: Ceramic capacitors are often marked with a code similar to the resistor colour code - two significant digits, plus the number of zeros, giving the value in pF.  Using this code, your "104pF" capacitor would really be 10 0000 pF or 100,000 pf = 0.1 uF.  The label on that package is incorrect.

Comment: Guys, I did what you wrote.. all of you. Still I hear only some scratching, but at least it's a way louder buzzing than before. At least one plus. Any ideas to fix it?

Comment: @MerryGR - Hi :-) "*Any ideas to fix it?*" Your question is now turning into a repair question, and those are only on-topic if you can show troubleshooting results and supply any requested information e.g. voltage readings (scope traces would be even better). We don't know how much you can (and are willing) to do. As a *minimum*, IMHO you need to take some clear, in-focus photos of your current circuitry, edit the question and add those photos at the bottom. If you're using a breadboard, then supply photos from different angles so we can see entry holes for component leads. Do you have a DMM?

Comment: It certainly ought to work at this point, so it's a problem of the reality not matching the schematic.  Do what @SamGibson asked, and if you have a DMM measure the voltage at pins 6 and 5 for us.  Note whether the meter is "bouncing" when you do, if you can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 10uF electrolytics, use those for the 10uF and for the "bypass" cap (negative goes to ground).

104 is 100nF so you can put two in series to get 50nF (which is 0.05uF) for the Zoebel network capacitor.

For the 250uF you can use one or two 100uF or three even, putting fewer will just make the lower frequencies roll off earlier, which is probably not very important for a small speaker.